# Fast way to preinitialize addresses in Python without iterating?

Tags: python, byte

I have binary file made of data packets that is serialized like this:

```
[Length][Payload][Length][Payload][Length][Payload]
```

The lengths are always 4 bytes and the value is variable, there is no specific pattern. The value of the length includes the 4 bytes of the `[Length]` itself. I need to extract the byte position in the file of the first bytes of every `[Length]`. For example:

```
00 00 02 00 FF FF FF FF FF ...
00 01 3C E5 FF FF FF FF FF ...
00 00 A5 90 FF FF FF FF FF ...
^
Need to save all these indexes
```

This works but it's slow, since I have more than 100k data packets per file:

```
data = mmap.mmap(filename.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
fileSize = os.path.getsize(filename.name)

address = 0
addresses = []

start = time.time()

while address < fileSize:
    pkt_length = bytes2int(data[address:(address + 4)])
    addresses.append(address)
    address += pkt_length

end = time.time()

print(len(addresses))
print(end-start)
```

What can I use to do this faster?

**EDIT 2** With os library

```
start = time.time()
addresses = []
fp = os.open(fileName, os.O_RDONLY)
while True:
    buf = os.read(fp, 4)
    if not buf:
        break
    size = int.from_bytes(buf, byteorder='big')
    addresses.append(os.lseek(fp, size-4, os.SEEK_CUR))  # -4 cause length already read

end = time.time()
print(len(addresses))
print(end-start)
```

Result:

```
45559456
179.0517611503601
```

**EDIT 1**
Here is a performance example with a 4.2GB file:

```
45559456
21.271047115325928
```

The RAM consumption goes pretty high too.

Comment: Your loop for 100k elements should take almost no time since there are no expensive operations inside. Why do you say it's slow? How much time does it take to finish and how are you measuring that time? Please add this info in the question.

Comment: I made a benchmark. I would say 100k is the absolute minimum, in other cases they go higher.

Comment: Python is a really nice language... for not too heavy things! That is the reason why tools like numpy and scipy were invented: to be able to process faster lengthy operations. If you have higher requirements that what Python can offer, maybe you should considere using C or C++ languages.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's some test code:

```
import random
import os
import time
import sys
import mmap

import psutil

K = 1024
MB = K * K

FILE_LEN = 1024 * MB
MIN_BLOCK = 1 * K
MAX_BLOCK = 50 * K

NUM_TESTS = 5


def init():
    sizes = []
    buf = []

    while sum(sizes) < FILE_LEN:
        sz = random.randint(MIN_BLOCK, MAX_BLOCK)
        sizes.append(sz)
        buf.append(sz.to_bytes(length=4, byteorder='big') + b'\xFF' * (sz - 4))

    fd = os.open(PATH, os.O_CREAT | os.O_WRONLY)
    os.write(fd, b''.join(buf))
    os.fsync(fd)
    os.close(fd)

    print('ok')

    return sizes


def timer(fn):
    m1 = psutil.Process().memory_info().rss
    t1 = time.time()
    res = fn()
    t2 = time.time()
    m2 = psutil.Process().memory_info().rss
    fs = os.path.getsize(PATH)
    return f'{fn.__name__:10s}: {fs // MB} MB,  {len(res)} blocks in {(t2 - t1):.2f} s, RAM= {(m2 - m1) // MB} MB'


# readers

def test_os():
    fd = os.open(PATH, os.O_RDONLY)
    res = []
    while True:
        buf = os.read(fd, 4)
        if not buf:
            break
        siz = int.from_bytes(buf, byteorder='big')
        res.append(siz)
        os.lseek(fd, siz - 4, os.SEEK_CUR)
    os.close(fd)
    return res


def test_fp():
    res = []
    with open(PATH, 'rb') as fp:
        while True:
            buf = fp.read(4)
            if not buf:
                break
            siz = int.from_bytes(buf, byteorder='big')
            res.append(siz)
            fp.seek(siz - 4, os.SEEK_CUR)
    return res


def test_mm():
    fileSize = os.path.getsize(PATH)
    address = 0
    adresses = []
    with open(PATH, 'rb') as fp:
        data = mmap.mmap(fp.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
        while address < fileSize:
            pkt_length = int.from_bytes(data[address:(address + 4)], byteorder='big')
            adresses.append(address)
            address += pkt_length
    return adresses


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PATH = sys.argv[2]

    if sys.argv[1] == 'init':
        init()
        exit()

    fns = [fn for name, fn in globals().items() if name.startswith('test_')]
    for _ in range(NUM_TESTS):
        random.shuffle(fns)
        out = []
        for fn in fns:
            out.append(timer(fn))
        print('\n'.join(sorted(out)))
        print()
```

How to use it:

- (uses `psutil`, `pip3 install psutil`)
- save as `test.py`
- invoke `test.py init xx`, where `xx` is a filename. This creates a 1GB file with random blocks
- if necessary, `cat xx xx xx xx > yy` to create a bigger file
- run `test.py test xx`

Results on my machine:

```
test_fp   : 5120 MB,  206735 blocks in 0.37 s, RAM= 6 MB
test_mm   : 5120 MB,  206735 blocks in 0.19 s, RAM= 10 MB
test_os   : 5120 MB,  206735 blocks in 0.27 s, RAM= 4 MB

test_fp   : 5120 MB,  206735 blocks in 0.36 s, RAM= 4 MB
test_mm   : 5120 MB,  206735 blocks in 0.19 s, RAM= 6 MB
test_os   : 5120 MB,  206735 blocks in 0.27 s, RAM= 6 MB

test_fp   : 5120 MB,  206735 blocks in 0.37 s, RAM= 6 MB
test_mm   : 5120 MB,  206735 blocks in 0.19 s, RAM= 6 MB
test_os   : 5120 MB,  206735 blocks in 0.27 s, RAM= 5 MB

test_fp   : 5120 MB,  206735 blocks in 0.37 s, RAM= 4 MB
test_mm   : 5120 MB,  206735 blocks in 0.19 s, RAM= 6 MB
test_os   : 5120 MB,  206735 blocks in 0.27 s, RAM= 4 MB

test_fp   : 5120 MB,  206735 blocks in 0.37 s, RAM= 4 MB
test_mm   : 5120 MB,  206735 blocks in 0.19 s, RAM= 6 MB
test_os   : 5120 MB,  206735 blocks in 0.27 s, RAM= 5 MB
```

The bottom line: mmap rules!

Comment: Slight improvement:
`45559456`
`19.28097701072693`

Comment: cool. Try replacing `open`  and `seek` with low-level file functions (`os.open` and `os.lseek`). Theoretically, these should be faster.

Comment: o___O `45559456` `179.0517611503601`
Could you have a look if you agree with the implementation in the EDIT 2?